# How to getsharedpreference for parameters

Tags: android, parameters, sharedpreferences

is it possible to get sharedprocedure for parameter 
cause i would like to have

```
parameters.setPreviewFrameRate(20);
parameters.setPreviewSize(352, 288);
camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
```

as a setting so the user can change thoose values

i tryed with this but it can't be initalized

```
    String PreviewFPS;
    String Previewsize;
    String Displayor;

    PreviewFPS = setingPreferences.getString("previewfps", "");
    Previewsize = setingPreferences.getString("screensize", "");
    Displayor = setingPreferences.getString("orientation", "");

    parameters.setPreviewFrameRate(PreviewFPS);
    parameters.setPreviewSize(Previewsize);
    camera.setDisplayOrientation(Displayor);
```

Comment: Yeah it is possible :)

Comment: how as i can't apply it